# Не получается изменить цвет кнопок тулбара

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Я могу изменить цвет каждой отдельной кнопки

```
 UIToolbar* tb = [[self navigationController] toolbar];
 for (UIBarButtonItem * item in tb.items)
        item.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

но не могу изменить цвет всего тулбара 
`[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]] ;`

Как сделать?

Comment: NSLog("%@", [[self navigationController] toolbar]); проверьте не nil ли он

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С выходом iOS 7.0 изменился метод:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR

UIToolBar *tBar;
tBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[tBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
```